# How to get products from two categories with and condition in woocommerce using url parameters

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get products that has assigned two categories in the admin cat1 and cat2.

and in url I am tring to put somthing like below

```
https://www.example.com/?product_cat=cat1,cat2
```

now what I want that all product that has assigned both of these categories not a single one. show on list
currenly products from both categories are display.

means

```
p1 -> cat1
p2-> cat2
p3-> cat1, cat2
```

so curently 3 products are showing but i want that only p3 should show.

Comment: Can you share the function you are using to do this?

Comment: @Howard I havenyt found any hook or function do it. thats why ask here. Do you have any idea

Comment: @RajkumarGour Did you find any solution?

Comment: @imabdullah not yet